# Adding encryption to a Twisted protocol

Tags: python, encryption, twisted

Supose I have a server for which I want to write a twisted client. This server speaks a certain binary protocol and all data passed between the server and client is XORed.

From reading about twisteds built-in `TLSTransport` I'm thinking this should be implemented as some sort of custom transport (XORTCPTransport?) to decouple the protocol itself from the encryption but I have no idea if this is the right way to do it or how to go about doing it.

So - is this the right way to implement this encryption scheme? If so, how would I go about implementing a new twisted transport?

Comment: You should just use TLS for encryption.  If there's a good reason not to, you should probably mention it in your question.  It would be irresponsible for someone to help you **actually** implement a Xor-based "encryption" transport.

Comment: I fully understand that xoring something is a horrible horrible way to encrypt data, but the way the server receives data is beyond my control.

Comment: Seems like the way to go, but I'm afraid you'll have to try yourself. The chance that you find someone here that has a pre-baked answer for this is minimal. If unsure, you may want to try and get in contact with the twisted devs. Usually devs are fine with such specific questions :)